# Understanding the working of a method annotated with both @scheduled(fixedRate=) and @async in springboot

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-boot, concurrency

A method annotated with `@Scheduled` is executed by `ThreadPoolTaskScheduler` having a default pool size of 1, whereas when a method is annotated with `@Async` it is executed by `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` asynchronously.

Given I wanted to execute multiple invocations of the same scheduled method asynchronously I annotated the same with both `@Scheduled(fixedRate=)` and `@Async`.

```
//execute once every second
@Scheduled(fixedRate = 1000)
@Async
public void pullDataFromExternalServer() throws InterruptedException {
   //do something
}
```

Although I got the result I wanted I'm unable to understand the internal working behind the same. Which threadpool was used ? What was the execution flow ?

Comment: Both were used. First the scheduling uses the `TaskExecutor` to schedule/trigger the task. Due to the `@Async` control is then passed to the `TaskExecutor`.

Comment: You can also log the name of the thread executing your method

Comment: @M.Deinum Even I thought the same but then I'm curious about the internal implementation of the same. Also, can we achieve the same functionality(running a single scheduled task parallely) using just the java concurrent api ?

Comment: What I described is more or less the implementation. There is no coordination between the 2, it is just 2 separate mechanisms doing there thing.

Comment: @M.Deinum There seems to be some coordination acc to me (correct me if I'm wrong), a **scheduled** task uses `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` for scheduling as well as executing the tasks and it can't run the same scheduled tasks parallely. But with `@Async` in picture it passes the execution to `ThreadPoolExecutor` and now can run parallely.

Comment: No it doesn't and there isn't any coordination. It is just both mechanisms operating on the thing they should be doing. Nothing is passed around, they don't even know about each other. Due the the async nature the task (from the scheduler point-of-view) is done immediately and thus frees up the thread immediately. This is just how the taskscheduler works, for the scheduler everything is done. Due to the `@Async` this will no run it in the background. All is transparent and they don't know about each other.

Comment: @M.Deinum oh grt bedankt for the explanation now it's clear to me :). Do you think we can achieve the same without annotations ?

Comment: You can also call the `TaskExecutor` yourself instead of `@Async` which will achieve the same result.

Comment: @M.Deinum I tried something similar earlier, calling a `@Async` method inside the scheduled method so that the execution is completed instantly and the thread is free, but to my surprise the async method used the same thread for execution.

Comment: If that `@Async` method is on the same class it won't work, it will only work if the `@Async` method is on a different class.

Comment: @M.Deinum Yup, it was already in a different class. Issue was I didn't register that class as a component. It's working now, thx for your inputs.